# WinHTTPRequest Automation Error (2147024769)

Tags: dll, vb6, winhttprequest

I've recently changed from Winsock to WinHTTPRequest however when this line runs:

```
Set WinHttpReq = New WinHttpRequest
```

I receieve an Automation Error :2147024769.

This code works fine on windows7/Windows server 2008, however is failing in Windows 2003.

Is this a problem with the winhttp.dll not being found on Windows server 2003?

Comment: It is a "file not found" error code, can't find a DLL it needs.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find what DLL is missing.  Fwiw, the download for winhttp5.dll was removed 11 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using WinHTTP as a Side-by-side Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384082(v=vs.85).aspx) if you need to use WinHttp 5.1 on Win2003 Server SP1 or later.  A sample manifest can be found there but to make use of the information you'll need an understanding of manifest use in VB6 applications.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me realize I made a error when generating the manifest files. I am running MMM(MakeMyManifest) on a Win7 machine and I never realized that Win2003's winhttp.dll is not in the same location. I've removed the dependency and it seems to work now. However is this the correct approach or poor practise?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "removed the dependency."  The winhttp.dll is not deployable but part of the OS.  So you should not try to isolate it using a tool like MMM.  If you need to use the winhttp.dll assembly on Win2003 via MMM you should create a customized version that can include the assembly-selection node in manifests.  No publicly released version of MMM does this.

Comment: MMM created a list of dependencies based on what my application was using and when I changed to WinHTTPRequest it included winHttp.dll with the location C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll. Not including this dependency has fixed the automation error I was getting.

Comment: Ahh.  Yes, there are many libraries you should not attempt to isolate and distribute.  MMM has a list of the common ones to hard-exclude but it isn't all-encompassing so the developer still has to have some knowledge.  Glad you got past the problem!